# What does this line in the Viterbi algorithm specifically do?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, notation, viterbi

[image: Viterbi line]

I am more concerned in understanding the assignment arrow to the left followed by max s'=1 to N. Disregard the semantics of the variables.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a recursive formula to determine the value of *viterbi[s,t]* for a given value of *s* and *t*.

In fact, *viterbi* is a matrix of *N* rows, and *s* is a row number in that matrix, and *t* a column number.

The value in the cell at *s,t* of the matrix is determined by taking all values in the previous column (column *t-1*, and row *s'* going from 1 to *N*),
-- which are supposed to be already known -- and multiplying them by specific values from two other matrices (I ignore their role in this, but these matrices are a given, and the value of *s*, *s'* and *t* determine which value to pick from those matrices).

From all these *N* products, the greatest is taken.

When you start with known values for the first column (*t* = 1), you can find with this formula the values in the second column, and when you have those, the third, ...etc.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now!

Comment: Glad it was useful to you.